# Remove child node from xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am generating xml code from mysql data. but it repeteadly generating item node before every node. please give me solution that how to remove the item node. my code are.any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
header('Content-type: text/xml');
include 'XMLParser.class.php';
$qry = mysql_query("select * from store") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$xml = XMLParser::encode($result,'response');
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

And ouput are in which item node is repeating before every node. please suggest me how to remove this item node:

> ```
> <response><item>3</item><id>3</id><item>Oxxo</item><name>Oxxo</name><item>avatar.png</item><image>avatar.png</image><item>ludhiyana</item><address>ludhiyana</address><item>9:00-17:00</item><open_close>9:00-17:00</open_close><item>dfsghxg</item><city>dfsghxg</city><item>465476</item><phone>465476</phone><item>0</item><drop_ins>0</drop_ins><item>500</item><cost>500</cost><item>0</item><include_mats>0</include_mats><item>400</item><mat_fee>400</mat_fee><item>28.6139391,77.20902120000005</item><lat_long>28.6139391,77.20902120000005</lat_long><item>2015-02-03
> ```
>
> 15:46:582015-02-03
>   15:46:5811

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array accepts a second parameter to indicate the way you want to retrieve data (Accepted values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH). By default it returns both associative array and numeric indices (MYSQL_BOTH). You can use:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```